# Scattering of electron anti-neutrino on hydrogen (Feyman diagram)

Tags: feynman-diagrams

Does anyone have a reference how the (lowest-order) Feynman diagrams for the scattering of an electron anti-neutrino $\overline\nu_e$ on a hydrogen atom would look like? I'm a bit confused about the fact that the proton consists of multiple quarks.

Comment: Aka [inverse beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay)

Comment: The Feynman diagram looks similar to that of $\beta^+$ decay, shown here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488111/123208