# Can a single nucleon undergo beta decay an infinite number of times?

Tags: radiation, neutrons, protons

Can a single nucleon (i.e., neutron or proton) undergo beta decay (+ or -)an infinite number of times?  If so, how does this square vs. the principle of conservation of mass/energy?  If not, what are the limiting factors?

Comment: Just how would it do that?

Answer (score 3):

[Beta plus decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2+_decay_2) of a proton requires energy to be added to the proton. That is, the energy of the final products is greater than the energy of the proton and the difference in energy has to be supplied from somewhere.

In a nucleus the energy can be supplied by rearrangements in the structure of the nucleus, but for an isolated proton there is nothing to supply the energy and consequently an isolated proton cannot undergo beta plus decay.

This means you cannot start with a neutron and have a continuous series of beta then beta plus decays. The neutron can beta decay once to create the proton, and the process stops there. For more on this see [How can beta plus decay be possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488007/how-can-beta-plus-decay-be-possible)

Comment: Thank you!  This nails it for me!